# Re-write dynamic textbox after button is pressed

Tags: excel, checkbox, dynamic, vba

I've created a code in VBA to collect data using a multi-page control. In each page, I've added checkboxes dynamically based on rows from the worksheet in Excel and, for each checkbox, there's a textbox and 2 command buttons, just like the image below:

Input Window:
[image]

The code to automatically add controls is:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
fmat_disp.Value = 0
fmat_set.Value = 0


'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Inspeção de Mecânica
Sheets("Mecânica").Activate
n_anom = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("1:1")) - 1
AreasInspecao.mecanica.ScrollHeight = 10 + 18 * (n_anom)
For i = 1 To n_anom
'Selecionar anomalia
Set SelAnom = AreasInspecao.mecanica.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "sel_anom_" & i)
SelAnom.Caption = Worksheets("Mecânica").Cells(1, i + 1)
SelAnom.AutoSize = True
SelAnom.Height = 18
SelAnom.Left = 5
SelAnom.Top = 5 + (SelAnom.Height) * (i - 1)
SelAnom.Tag = i
```

Same goes to the textbox and plus/minus buttons, only changing the captions.

What I want is:
1) when CHECKBOX is CHECKED, respective TEXTBOX must show 1
2) when MINUS sign is PRESSED, respective TEXTBOX must decrement
3) when PLUS sign is PRESSED, respective TEXTBOX must increment
4) when "Finalizar Inspeção" is PRESSED, all data collected must be sent to Excel, filling a worksheet.

I simply don't know how to link each button/checkbox to your respective textbox without creating a subroutine for each one! I'll have ~500 subroutines....that's impossible to manage manually....

Comment: Where is the image?

Comment: sorry...imgurl link to image added!

Comment: If you're adding controls dynamically then you need something like this: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/05/vba-control-arrays/   That shows you how to capture the events: all you need to do is name your controls such that the groups of related controls can be identified in the triggered code.

Comment: but in my case, for each textbox, only the two buttons (plus/minus) next to them control it...this will require me to create events for each textbox? or am i wrong?

Comment: You need two collections of class instances following the method shown in the link: one for the checkboxes and one for the buttons.  The textboxes don't raise any events in the process you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here's a rough outline for handling the click events on the checkboxes and buttons.

First two custom classes for capturing the clicks: each of these is very simple - all they do is call a method on the userform with the clicked control as an argument.

```
'clsCheck
Public WithEvents chk As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub chk_Click()
    frmExample.HandleClick chk
End Sub

'clsButton
Public WithEvents btn As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub btn_Click()
    frmExample.HandleClick btn
End Sub
```

Userform code - my form is named "frmExample".

Note the naming convention which allows groups of controls to be treated as a "unit".

```
Option Explicit

'These two global collections hold instances of the custom classes
Dim colCheckBoxes As Collection
Dim colButtons As Collection


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Const CON_HT As Long = 18
    Dim x As Long, cbx As MSForms.CheckBox, t
    Dim btn As MSForms.CommandButton, txt As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim oCheck As clsCheck, oButton As clsButton

    Set colCheckBoxes = New Collection
    Set colButtons = New Collection

    For x = 1 To 10

        t = 5 + CON_HT * (x - 1)

        Set cbx = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "cbox_" & x)
        cbx.Caption = "Checkbox" & x
        cbx.Width = 80
        cbx.Height = CON_HT
        cbx.Left = 5
        cbx.Top = t
        colCheckBoxes.Add GetCheckHandler(cbx) '<< save in collection

        Set btn = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "btnplus_" & x)
        btn.Caption = "+"
        btn.Height = CON_HT
        btn.Width = 20
        btn.Left = 90
        btn.Top = t
        btn.Enabled = False '<<buttons start off disabled
        colButtons.Add GetButtonHandler(btn) '<< save in collection

        Set btn = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "btnminus_" & x)
        btn.Caption = "-"
        btn.Height = CON_HT
        btn.Width = 20
        btn.Left = 130
        btn.Top = t
        btn.Enabled = False '<<buttons start off disabled
        colButtons.Add GetButtonHandler(btn) '<< save in collection

        'no events are captured for the textboxes...
        Set txt = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", "txt_" & x)
        txt.Width = 30
        txt.Height = CON_HT
        txt.Left = 170
        txt.Top = t

    Next x

End Sub

'All "clicked" controls saved in instances of the custom classes
'   get passed here. Handle based on control type/name
Public Sub HandleClick(ctrl As MSForms.Control)
    Dim num
    num = Split(ctrl.Name, "_")(1) 'which set of controls are we working with?
    Dim txt As MSForms.TextBox
    'get the matching text box...
    Set txt = Me.Controls("txt_" & num)
    If ctrl.Name Like "cbox_*" Then
        If ctrl.Value Then txt.Value = 1
        Me.Controls("btnplus_" & num).Enabled = ctrl.Value
        Me.Controls("btnminus_" & num).Enabled = ctrl.Value
    ElseIf ctrl.Name Like "btnplus_*" Then
        txt.Value = txt.Value + 1
    ElseIf ctrl.Name Like "btnminus_*" Then
        txt.Value = txt.Value - 1
    End If
End Sub


'couple of "factory" functions for the event-handling classes
Private Function GetCheckHandler(cb As MSForms.CheckBox)
    Dim rv As New clsCheck
    Set rv.chk = cb
    Set GetCheckHandler = rv
End Function

Private Function GetButtonHandler(btn As MSForms.CommandButton)
    Dim rv As New clsButton
    Set rv.btn = btn
    Set GetButtonHandler = rv
End Function
```

Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k74c08m0zkwn9l7/tmpFormEvents.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: thanks, Tim!
it worked like a charm, altough I had to make a few modifications in my interface...
i think i can't do this inside a multipage, so i've created frames linked to buttons and made one frame visible at a time, based on which button was activated